# QBFC 10 `sessionManager.BeginSession` System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

I am getting this QBFC10 error `System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

The error points to this code `sessionManager.BeginSession(@"D:\CompanyFile.qbw", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);` below.

If remove the file path `@"D:\CompanyFile.qbw"` and leave it empty `""` it works. But that is not the intention. I need to have the file path there in order for me to run the application even if QuickBooks is not running.

```
private void BtnQuery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool sessionBegun = false;
    bool connectionOpen = false;
    QBSessionManager sessionManager = null;

    try
    {
        sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
        IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 10, 0);
        requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

        IItemInventoryQuery ItemInventoryQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendItemInventoryQueryRq();

        sessionManager.OpenConnection2("", "AppName", ENConnectionType.ctLocalQBD);
        connectionOpen = true;
        sessionManager.BeginSession(@"D:\CompanyFile.qbw", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
        sessionBegun = true;

        IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);

        sessionManager.EndSession();
        sessionBegun = false;
        sessionManager.CloseConnection();
        connectionOpen = false;

        String xml = responseMsgSet.ToXMLString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
        if (sessionBegun)
        {
            sessionManager.EndSession();
        }
        if (connectionOpen)
        {
            sessionManager.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

I also raised this issue with Intuit Developer support awaiting their response. I am hoping anyone here is familiar with QuickBooks API (QBFC).

Comment: Is this in a program you made yourself? Do you get a stacktrace? Do you have any unsafe or native code?

Comment: Yes, it is the program I am working on right now and I got the stacktrace. The error originates in my `Xml` API code. I am not sure if this is what you are referring to as unsafe or native code. I can show you the code if you want.

Comment: Yes, failures should include the full message, including at least some of the stacktrace, and the relevant parts of the code the triggers the error. AccessViolationExceptions means the process tried to access memory not allocated to it. That should typically not happen in .net applications since you cannot access memory directly. Unless you have voluntary opted out from the protection with the "unsafe" specifier, or call native (i.e. c/c++) code that does not give any protection.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP says "I'm positive that my code has nothing to do with this. Therefore, I won't show any code-related details here." which means it's not a question about code.

Comment: I'm guessing you are not using QBFC properly, which is causing your issue, but again: hard to say without seeing code. Very possibly Windows 11 is using a different build of .NET which makes the error turn up quicker or something like that

Comment: I will post my code in a while. I just need more time to figure out where the error originates. I am looking at the QBFC right now. One thing I just realized now, it appears to be not a Windows issue. Please give me a little time.

Comment: I edited the entire question and provided the code as well.